# ispac not created when SSIS Project built

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

With a 2012 SSDT database project and a Integration Services project within it using project deployment model, after a build, a `.ispac` file is not created for me.  Is there a setting or option that is necessary to allow this to be created?

The project builds successfully, and successfully creates the `.dacpac` file too.  Building from the solution or individual project, the `.dacpac` file is created, and I see both projects are built successfully when built from the solution.  I can also successfully create a `.SSISDeploymentManifest` file too.  Of course, the run the all the packages without error as well.

Also, the Non-Default Properties Report shows only MaxConcurrentExecutables and EnableConfigurations for project level properties have non default values.

I feel like there is something small I'm missing.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a package is converted to use the package deployment model, a .ispac is not created when the project is built.  It is only created when the project is using the project deployment model.  The answer was in the question the entire time...